# Java inheritance structure problem

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have just implemented some classes:

```
public abstract class Job<T extends ViewerUnion>{
[...]
}

public abstract class ReturnValueJob<T, S extends ViewerUnion> extends Job<S> {
[...]
}

public class MyReturnJob extends ReturnValueJob<Foo, Baa> {
[...]
}

public class JobExecuter {
public static void execute(List<Job> jobList){
for(Job actJob: jobList){
    actJob.startJob();
}
for(Job actJob: jobList){
    actJob.awaitTimeoutOrFinish();
}
}
}
```

Now I want to execute this code:

```
List<Job> list = new LinkedList<MyReturnJob>();
JobExecuter.execute(list);
```

But Java gives me some error while compiling:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList to List

I don't know why because the `MyReturnJob` is inheriting the `Job`.
If I change the definition of the list to `LinkedList<MyReturnJob> list = new LinkedList<MyReturnJob>();`

The same error is thrown on `JobExecuter.execute(list);`

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Till

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What wrong here??

The problem is not the change from `LinkedList` to `List`, but the change in the *contained type*.  Java generics are not *covariant*, which means you cannot even do:

```
LinkedList<Job> = new LinkedList<MyReturnJob>();
```

#### Details...

For more info, read the ["Java theory and practice: Generics gotchas"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) article. Here its relevant part:

> *It turns out there's a good reason it doesn't work (...): **It would break the type safety generics were supposed to provide**. Imagine you could assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`. Then the following code would allow you to put something that wasn't an `Integer` into a `List<Integer>`:*
>
> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
> ln.add(new Float(3.1415));
> ```

#### ... applied back to context

The article example code can be translated into the context of this question like this:

```
List<MyReturnJob> li = new LinkedList<MyReturnJob>();
List<Job> ln = li; // illegal
ln.add(new FooJob());
```

where `FooJob` is declared as:

```
public abstract FooJob extends Job<ViewerUnion> {
[...]
}
```

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth. Ok, thank you very much. If I change my Listdef to `LinkedList<MyReturnJob> list = new LinkedList<MyReturnJob>();` and the JobExecuter to `public static void execute(List<? extends Job> jobList){[...]` everything will work fine?

Comment: @Till: What is `GetBetAmountJob`?

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth Sorry. Typo, now its MyReturnJob

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot assign collections with different parameterized types, even if those parameterized types would normally be assignable.

What you're probably looking for is something like:

```
List<Job> list = new LinkedList<Job>();
JobExecuter.execute( list );

public static void execute( List<? extends Job> jobList )
{ ... }
```